# Sampling from the uniform distribution

Tags: probability-theory

Is there an efficient classical algorithm that generates samples from the uniform distribution (or a distribution that is close to the uniform distribution in total variation distance), over the set $\{0, 1\}^{n}$, for a fixed $n$?

We can easily express the uniform distribution in terms of a formula:

$Pr(X = x) = \frac{1}{N}$, for each $x \in \{0, 1\}^{n}$ and $N = 2^{n}$.

My guess is that any distribution that can be expressed in terms of an explicit formula can be efficiently sampled from, but I can't find a concrete proof.

Comment: Please ask only one question per post.  The uniform distribution on what set?  What are your thoughts?  Can you think of any algorithm?  What prevents you from answering the first question on your own?  For the second question, you'd need to define what you mean by an "analytic description" of a distribution.

Comment: Edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just sample $n$ bits, concatenate them, and output the result.

Comment: How do you "sample" a bit? Do you just toss a coin? I can't seem to relate this with a physical process that the computer would be doing.

Comment: If you want to understand pseudo-random number generation, and don't have access to a copy of TAOCP, the PCG paper is probably your best bet. https://www.pcg-random.org/paper.html

Comment: @BlackHat18, randomized algorithms are assumed to have access to the ability to generate random bits.  It's not clear what the source of your confusion is and whether you are asking a theoretical or practical question.  Perhaps you might find it useful to find a textbook on randomized algorithms and learn about that area?